# Is there any generalization of the convexity of $t^{-p}$ for $p > 0$ for real symmetric positive definite matrices?

Tags: matrices, operator-theory, convexity

Let $p > 0$. On the positive reals, $t \mapsto t^{-p}$, is a convex function, as can be seen easily by a plot or differentiation.

However, unfortunately, unless $p \in (0, 1]$, the map $f_p(X) = X^{-p}$ is not convex on the cone of real symmetric positive definite matrices in general.

However I am wondering if there is any other generalization that holds for operators/real symmetric positive definite matrices? There is one obvious one: which is that
$$
\Big(\frac{A + B}{2}\Big)^{-p} \preceq \frac{1}{2} A^{-p} + \frac{1}{2} B^{-p}, 
$$
when $A, B$ are real symmetric positive definite and are simultaneously diagonalizable.
However this is somehow `cheating' because it simply boils down to the scalar inequalities in this case by rotation to the appropriate basis.

Is there anything more nontrivial that can be said?